# I have a problem with VLOOKUP formula in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, vlookup

I am not very good at VLOOKUP formulas and that is why I am asking this question. I want my vlookup formula to fetch names, age and risk factors from a specific address. The one I am using right now to fetch names is this;=vlookup(A3, 'Pivot Table 13'!A206:D566, 2, false). But the problem is that it is fetching only one name(or age or risk factor). For example, if it is supposed to fetch names from 'Aligiri' it will only fetch the first name 'Adam Yoosuf'. Can someone please help me on how to go about this
[Pivot table vlookup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvkAb.png)

PS: [Here is the link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KaNehIpTg9jHh0BLDVI1hMZzm-UhmJPFB7Cwu2j-9XQ/edit?usp=sharing)

My area of interest is in cell A27 in the 'Dashboard' tab. I want to have the name, age and risk factor displayed there when I select an address from the cell A3 in the same tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be easier to answer with a spreadsheet instead of an image. In your Pivot Table, please check "repeat value" for current address, then use query instead of vlookup.

```
=query('Pivot Table 13'!A206:D566,"select B,C,D where A='"& A3 &"' ")
```

adapt the query accoring to your regional parameters and structure of your spreadsheet.

Comment: I have edited the question by including a link. Please check it out

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `Filter` function since all information are to be display with sequence row:

```
=FILTER(C16:F24,C16:C24=I17)
```

[image]